# NullPointerException with JPA creteria query with filter condition on where clause

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, filter, criteria

I have written creteria query, on where condition includes and, or, like operators with filter condition also. My creteria query execution works fine without filter condition. But if I give filter condition it gives me NullPointerException. I have referred below link, but its not with filter condition

[JPA 2.0 Criteria Query with Hibernate](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/jpa-2-0-criteria-query-with-hibernate.html)

Creteria query code:

```
List<TbiDDDetailView> tbiDDDetailViews  = tbiDDDetailViewDao.findByDomainIdAndMetricNameLike(domainId, searchString);

            CriteriaBuilder cb=em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<TbiDDDetailView> qry =cb.createQuery(TbiDDDetailView.class);
            Root root = qry.from(TbiDDDetailView.class);
            Root config = qry.from(TbiDDConfigMaster.class);

            List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
            orderList = getSort(cb,root,sortProperties, sortTypes, null);
            qry.orderBy(orderList);

            List creteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
            Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("ddConfigId"), config.get("ddConfigId"));
            creteriaList.add(predicate1);

            Predicate predicate2 = cb.equal(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("domainId"), domainId);
            creteriaList.add(predicate2);

            Predicate predicate3 = cb.or(cb.like(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("keywords"), "%"+searchString+"%"),cb.like(root.get("metricName"),"%"+searchString+"%"));

            CriteriaQuery<TbiDDDetailView> criteriaQuery = qry.select(cb.construct(TbiDDDetailView.class, root.get("ddConfigId"),root.get("metricName"),root.get("ddType"),
                    root.get("ddName"),root.get("discoveryId"),root.get("keywords")));

            //filter
            Predicate filterCondition = cb.conjunction();
            try {
                Path<Integer> pathFilter = (Path<Integer>) getPath("isActive", root, null);
                filterCondition=cb.and(cb.equal(pathFilter,"Y"));
                filterCondition = getFilters(filterCondition, cb, root, property, operator, value, null);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.info("Error In filter isActive", e);
            }
            qry.where(filterCondition,cb.and((Predicate[]) creteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])), predicate3);
            TypedQuery<TbiDDDetailView> tq = em.createQuery(qry); //NullPointerException at this line
return tbiDDDetailViews = tq.getResultList();
```

Error trace:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.LikePredicate.render(LikePredicate.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.AbstractSimplePredicate.render(AbstractSimplePredicate.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.CompoundPredicate.render(CompoundPredicate.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.CompoundPredicate.render(CompoundPredicate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.CompoundPredicate.render(CompoundPredicate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.CompoundPredicate.render(CompoundPredicate.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.CompoundPredicate.render(CompoundPredicate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.predicate.CompoundPredicate.render(CompoundPredicate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.QueryStructure.render(QueryStructure.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.interpret(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:736)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.service.ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl.getViewMatrics(ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl.java:8841)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.getViewMatrics(Unknown Source)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.restservice.service.RestServiceImpl.getViewMatrics(RestServiceImpl.java:2897)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.restservice.service.RestrsService.getMatrics(RestrsService.java:10904)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.security.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
20817 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] ERROR com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.service.ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl  - Error in listing Metrics
20819 [http-bio-9090-exec-3] INFO  com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.service.ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl  - Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:522)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.getViewMatrics(Unknown Source)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.restservice.service.RestServiceImpl.getViewMatrics(RestServiceImpl.java:2897)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.restservice.service.RestrsService.getMatrics(RestrsService.java:10904)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.security.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    ... 71 more
```

Normal MySql Query:

```
select d.* from tbi_datadiscovery_detail_view d join tbi_dd_config_master c on d.dd_metric_id = c.dd_metric_config_id 
where c.domain_id = 1 and d.dd_metric_name like "%exp%" or d.key_words like "%exp%"
```

This MySql query I have converted into `Creteria query` using `Predicate`. Please let me know where I am doing wrong in using filter condition

Comment: It's the problem with LikePredicate & NPE is always because of user's fault. Since, you haven't posted the entire stacktrace, it's hard to find where the NPE occurred. Debug the code and you would come to know

Comment: I have edited my question and added full stack trace

Comment: You should start by looking at `ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl.java:8841` and better if you can debug the code and see where you are getting the NPE

Comment: I debug the code and checked. Error is coming 'TypedQuery<TbiDDDetailView> tq = em.createQuery(qry);' for this

Comment: what is your hibernate version?

Comment: @arch, If this is the exact line for NPE, then either your em is null, or qry is null, which i doubt

Comment: @wero Hibernate 4.3.0

Comment: @Sategroup query is taking null as I am adding filterCondition at qry.where(filterCondition,cb.and((Predicate[]) creteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])), predicate3);

Comment: Can you check - when building the query - if `root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("keywords")` and `root.get("metricName")` are not null?

Comment: @wero i checked.. they are not coming null

Comment: hibernate.LikePredicate throws a NPE when it shouldn't. The best you can do is to add the hibernate JPA sources to your project and remote debug the execution of the query, setting a breakpoint at LikePredicate:131 and see why it has a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got solution for my problem.

Problem was, I was adding `filterCondition` directly to `qry.where()` instead I should add it to `creteriaList` as I am doing with other `predicates`.

Changes in last few lines my code(`CriteriaQuery`):

```
//filter
Predicate filterCondition = cb.conjunction();
try {
    Path<Integer> pathFilter = (Path<Integer>) getPath("isActive", root, null);
    filterCondition=cb.and(cb.equal(pathFilter,"Y"));
    filterCondition = getFilters(filterCondition, cb, root, property, operator, value, null);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           log.info("Error In filter isActive", e);
    }
creteriaList.add(filterCondition);  
Predicate predicate3 = (cb.or(cb.like(root.get("tbiDDConfigMaster").get("keywords"), "%"+searchString+"%"),cb.like(root.get("metricName"),"%"+searchString+"%")));
creteriaList.add(predicate3);
qry.where(cb.and((Predicate[]) creteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
```